# grouping tables and horizontally showing?

Tags: tables

I want to align my two tables horizontally.

Here's my tables.

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
    &   TS    &  AT \\\hline
 1  &   3839    &   1341    \\\hline
 2  &   3887    &   1323    \\\hline
 3  &   3846    &   1345    \\\hline
 4  &   4111    &   1424    \\\hline
 5  &   3846    &   1359    \\\hline
 6  &   4179    &   1512    \\\hline
 7  &   3791    &   1395    \\\hline
 8  &   3643    &   1242    \\\hline
 9  &   3931    &   1427    \\\hline
 10 &   3572    &   1329    \\\hline
 Average    &   3864.5  &   1369.7 \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Example result of original}\label{tab:exorigin}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
    &   TS    &  AT \\\hline
 1  &   3839    &   1341    \\\hline
 2  &   3887    &   1323    \\\hline
 3  &   3846    &   1345    \\\hline
 4  &   4111    &   1424    \\\hline
 5  &   3846    &   1359    \\\hline
 6  &   4179    &   1512    \\\hline
 7  &   3791    &   1395    \\\hline
 8  &   3643    &   1242    \\\hline
 9  &   3931    &   1427    \\\hline
 10 &   3572    &   1329    \\\hline
 Average    &   3864.5  &   1369.7 \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Example result of mutant}\label{tab:exorigin2}

\end{table}
```

my table is now looks like this.

[image]

They are now 4.2 and 4.3 tables, but I want to make these 4.2a and 4.2b tables.

How can I put the tables horizontally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place each `tabular`-`caption`-`label` group in its own `minipage`, of width `0.5\textwidth`, use `\centering` directives to center the material inside the minipages, and be sure not to leave an empty line between the minipages.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\hrule % just to illustrate width of textblock
\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
    &   TS    &  AT \\\hline
 1  &   3839    &   1341    \\\hline
 2  &   3887    &   1323    \\\hline
 3  &   3846    &   1345    \\\hline
 4  &   4111    &   1424    \\\hline
 5  &   3846    &   1359    \\\hline
 6  &   4179    &   1512    \\\hline
 7  &   3791    &   1395    \\\hline
 8  &   3643    &   1242    \\\hline
 9  &   3931    &   1427    \\\hline
 10 &   3572    &   1329    \\\hline
 Average    &   3864.5  &   1369.7 \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Example result of original}\label{tab:exorigin}
\end{minipage}% % no space between the minipages!
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
    &   TS    &  AT \\\hline
 1  &   3839    &   1341    \\\hline
 2  &   3887    &   1323    \\\hline
 3  &   3846    &   1345    \\\hline
 4  &   4111    &   1424    \\\hline
 5  &   3846    &   1359    \\\hline
 6  &   4179    &   1512    \\\hline
 7  &   3791    &   1395    \\\hline
 8  &   3643    &   1242    \\\hline
 9  &   3931    &   1427    \\\hline
 10 &   3572    &   1329    \\\hline
 Average    &   3864.5  &   1369.7 \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Example result of mutant}\label{tab:exorigin2}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: You may also want to think seriously about giving your tables a more "open" look by (a) using no vertical lines, (b) getting rid of most horizontal lines, and (c) using the macros of the `booktabs` package instead of `\hline` to draw the remaining few lines. For the tables at hand, horizontal rules would ideally be employed only to indicate the very top (`\toprule`) and bottom (`\bottomrule`) of the `tabular` material and offset the header material from the body of the table (`\midrule`). Whitespace can be every bit as effective as a visual separator as lines are.

Separately, to "number" the subtables as "(a)" and "(b)", you could use `subtable` environments instead of `minipage` environments; be sure to provide a `\caption` for the overall table as well.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,subcaption,amsmath}
\begin{document}
%% Just for this example 
   \numberwithin{table}{section} 
   \setcounter{section}{4}
   \setcounter{table}{1}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{subtable}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}ccc@{}}
\toprule
    &   TS    &  AT \\
\midrule
 1  &   3839    &   1341    \\
 2  &   3887    &   1323    \\
 3  &   3846    &   1345    \\
 4  &   4111    &   1424    \\
 5  &   3846    &   1359    \\
\addlinespace
 6  &   4179    &   1512    \\
 7  &   3791    &   1395    \\
 8  &   3643    &   1242    \\
 9  &   3931    &   1427    \\
 10 &   3572    &   1329    \\
\addlinespace
 Average    &   3864.5  &   1369.7 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Example result of original}\label{tab:exorigin}
\end{subtable}
\hfill
\begin{subtable}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}ccc@{}}
\toprule
    &   TS    &  AT \\
\midrule
 1  &   3839    &   1341    \\
 2  &   3887    &   1323    \\
 3  &   3846    &   1345    \\
 4  &   4111    &   1424    \\
 5  &   3846    &   1359    \\
\addlinespace
 6  &   4179    &   1512    \\
 7  &   3791    &   1395    \\
 8  &   3643    &   1242    \\
 9  &   3931    &   1427    \\
 10 &   3572    &   1329    \\
\addlinespace
 Average    &   3864.5  &   1369.7 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Example result of mutant}\label{tab:exorigin2}
\end{subtable}
\caption{Two example results} \label{tab:overall}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: awesome, it successfully worked :) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This solution will label the table captions (a) and (b) besides horizontally aligning:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{subtable}{.5\linewidth}\centering
{\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
    &   TS    &  AT \\\hline
 1  &   3839    &   1341    \\\hline
 2  &   3887    &   1323    \\\hline
 3  &   3846    &   1345    \\\hline
 4  &   4111    &   1424    \\\hline
 5  &   3846    &   1359    \\\hline
 6  &   4179    &   1512    \\\hline
 7  &   3791    &   1395    \\\hline
 8  &   3643    &   1242    \\\hline
 9  &   3931    &   1427    \\\hline
 10 &   3572    &   1329    \\\hline
 Average    &   3864.5  &   1369.7 \\\hline
\end{tabular}}
\caption{Example result of original}\label{tab:exorigin}
\end{subtable}
\begin{subtable}{.5\linewidth}\centering
{\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
    &   TS    &  AT \\\hline
 1  &   3839    &   1341    \\\hline
 2  &   3887    &   1323    \\\hline
 3  &   3846    &   1345    \\\hline
 4  &   4111    &   1424    \\\hline
 5  &   3846    &   1359    \\\hline
 6  &   4179    &   1512    \\\hline
 7  &   3791    &   1395    \\\hline
 8  &   3643    &   1242    \\\hline
 9  &   3931    &   1427    \\\hline
 10 &   3572    &   1329    \\\hline
 Average    &   3864.5  &   1369.7 \\\hline
\end{tabular}}
\caption{Example result of mutant}\label{tab:exorigin2}
\end{subtable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: ahh.. there is subtable in latex. Thank you. :)